# insert value at the end of every record based on unique IDs

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have 2 files , one with Delimited and other one is Positional file.

These two files shares same unique ID's as shown below but both the files contains different information.

`del.txt`

```
11111|abc|01|||||||||

22222|xyz|09|||||||||
```

`pos.txt`

```
11111  abc newyork US 

22222  xyz dallas  US
```

The del.txt file consist of unique member id followed by name and Alternative ID separated by | (delimited) and 
similarly pos.txt has unique ID along with name except alternative id in positional format.

I want to insert alternative ID in pos.txt only if Unique Member ID matches in both the file as shown below

`pos.txt`

```
11111  abc newyork US 01

22222  xyz  dallas US 09
```

How can we achieve this using shell script?

Comment: Your `pos.txt` file still looks delimited, just by spaces instead of pipes. Will there ever be a case where there are no spaces between fields, or when a field has a space in the value?

Answer (score 3):

With this problem, I think the best way is using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'[ |]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$3;next}($1 in a){print $0" "a[$1]}' del.txt pos.txt 
11111  abc newyork US 01

22222  xyz dallas  US 09
```